# Regex substring of numbers before inverted comma

Tags: regex, postgresql

Hi i'm trying to extract all numbers (including decimals) before the ' character using PostgreSQL.

I'm not sure how to specify this because my regular expression is contained between these characters itself. See:

```
SUBSTRING(long_text, '[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)(?=')') as substring_feet
```

This results in the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "') as substring_feet
            --,SUBSTRING(long_text, (position((substring(long_text FROM '"
LINE 6: ...ng_text, '[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)(?=')') as subs...
                                                         ^
```

I have tried various escapes etc. but can't figure it out.

The [expression passes ok](https://regex101.com/r/rXsRLG/1) using the online tester because this doesn't account for the quotes needed for my query.

Comment: You need to escape the " ' " in oracle itself. " '' " (2 ...upper colons) escapes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all occurrences, you may use `regex_matches` function with `g` flag, but you must also make sure you have no capturing groups in the pattern, replace them with [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) ones (i.e. `(?:...)`). To use a single quote, double it (it is common knowledge).

Use something like

```
SELECT regexp_matches(long_text, '[+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)(?='')', 'g') as substring_feet
```

Note you may get rid of the lookahead if you wrap the part you want to extract with a *capturing* group (i.e. `(...)`):

```
SELECT regexp_matches(long_text, '([+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+))''', 'g') as substring_feet
```

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/CXJZK37412)

If you really have an **inverted comma**, use

```
SELECT regexp_matches(long_text, '([+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+))’', 'g') as substring_feet
```

See [another online demo](http://rextester.com/WBPB26247).

Comment: In your online example the input text is 'approx 3''' whereas in all the text fields I need to search it the text occurs as 

approx 5'.
roughly 2'.
height of 3'.

etc. (i.e the inverted comma is used just once)

Comment: @Beeman Was it an inverted comma? Why didn't you use it in the example in the question? Then use http://rextester.com/WBPB26247

Comment: sorry i've got my terminology mixed up: not an inverted comma but a single quotation mark as described in the example.

Comment: @Beeman Then my answer should be working for you. Please consider accepting then.

Comment: hi, no the example doesn't work because in my example the long_text field refers to a a column on a table that contains long passage of text. See my online example in the original question.

Comment: @Beeman [It **WORKS**](https://regex101.com/r/D6q423/1), it extracts `3`.

Comment: got it! thanks for your help and sorry for my confusion.